# How emulate 100% coverage for double check expression?

Tags: ruby, testing, code-coverage

I have some code, where there are two checks for zero price (for example).
If the first check fails, the second check will not reach the queue, or not?
How can I create a test that can cover 100% of this code?

```rb
def products
  # first check on zero price
  products = database.query 'SELECT * FROM product WHERE price > 0;'
  products.map do |product|

    # second check on zero price
    unless product[:price] > 0
      warn 'wrong price'
      next
    end

    # some operation under product
  end
end
```

Comment: Better question, are you sure you "need" both sets of code?  It's probably better to have your test ensure that the result of this includes no products with 0 price and then only have one check.

Comment: I cannot think of a reason why a database (by accident or randomly) would return products that do not match the condition. Why do you think you need the second check?

Answer (score 0):

True 100% coverage is really not practical. Unless your code is extremely self-contained and well-defined then proving [program correctness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correctness_(computer_science)) is basically impossible.

This relies on a database that could have bugs, CPUs that might malfunction, memory that might be unreliable, disks that can fail, filesystems that can be corrupted and so on. When testing, though, you can't take these into account, testing for rare random events is almost always unfounded paranoia.

Imagine the following code:

```
def return_items(items)
  items.each do |item|
    if (world_about_to_be_hit_by_asteroid?)
      warn "World about to be destroyed, may not be able to process this refund in time!"
    end

    item.return_to_inventory!

    if (item.could_not_be_returned_due_to_zombie_outbreak?)
      item.cancel_return!
      warn "The living dead are now taking over, return cancelled."
    end

    item.estimate_shipping unless (Alerts.speed_of_light_changed?)

    if (sun_about_to_explode?)
      warn "Head to shelter immediately."
    end
  end
end
```

Instead try and cover 100% of the functionality that you *can* reasonably test under the conditions you need it to operate. In this case are you testing that the database query produces the correct results? Are you testing that your database driver returns data? Are you testing against a data set that has a variety of prices, like -1, 0 and 1 to ensure you get only the one right records?

Putting `warn` in the middle of production code like this is an extremely bad habit and should be avoided. During development you may have "assert"-like statements that deliberately blow up the program if certain conditions are violated, but those should be reserved for only the most serious of situations, where proceeding would have catastrophic consequences.

The problem here is the method's not only overly paranoid, this is tin-foil hat coding, but doesn't communicate what it does. A better approach:

```
def products(above_price: 0)
  database.query('SELECT * FROM product WHERE price > ?', above_price)
end
```

Where you have confidence `database.query` will work because that code is tested somewhere else, like in the test suite for your database driver. You test your interaction with it like this:

```
# Create products at prices -1, 0, 1 and 100

assert_equal 2, products.length
assert_equal 1, products(above_price: 20).length
assert_equal 4, products(above_price: -100).length
```

Where you can test in more detail to make sure the correct products are returned and not just the right number of some random products.